# Designing a slowly changing dimension type 2 script with postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, dimensional-modeling

Let's say I have the following target table:

```
CREATE TABLE DimCustomer (
CustomerKey serial PRIMARY KEY,
    CustomerNum int NOT NULL,
    CustomerName varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    Planet varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    RowIsCurrent char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
    RowStartDate date NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    RowEndDate date NOT NULL DEFAULT '12/31/9999'
);

INSERT INTO DimCustomer
(CustomerNum, CustomerName, Planet,  RowStartDate) 
VALUES (101,'Anakin Skywalker', 'Tatooine',   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '101 days'),
       (102,'Yoda', 'Coruscant',  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '100 days'),
       (103,'Obi-Wan Kenobi', 'Coruscant',  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '100 days')
```

And I have a following staging table:

```
CREATE TABLE Staging_DimCustomer
(
    CustomerNum int NOT NULL,
    CustomerName varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    Planet varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    ChangeDate date NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    RankNo int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
)
INSERT INTO Staging_DimCustomer(CustomerNum, CustomerName, Planet, ChangeDate)
VALUES
(103,'Ben Kenobi', 'Coruscant',   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '99 days')
```

In the staging table, it looks like `'Obi-Wan Kenobi'`(`customernum 103`) changed his name to 
 `'Ben Kenobi'`. I want to create a script that implements scd type 2 and produces the following result(slowly changing dimension type 2):

[image]

Following is my attempt:

```
INSERT INTO DimCustomer (
  CustomerNum, CustomerName, Planet, RowIsCurrent, RowStartDate, RowEndDate
  ) 
 select CustomerNum, CustomerName, Planet, 'Y', ChangeDate, '12/31/9999'
 from Staging_DimCustomer 

 ON CONFLICT (CustomerNum) and RowIsCurrent = 'Y'
  DO UPDATE SET
    CustomerName = EXCLUDED.CustomerName,
    Planet = EXCLUDED.Planet,
    RowIsCurrent = 'N',
    RowEndDate = EXCLUDED.ChangeDate
```

I dont know how to look for the values that changed, update the existing rows to retire it and then insert the new rows with `rowiscurrent = 'Y'` flag. I am trying to model my solution based on this sql server article
http://www.made2mentor.com/2013/08/how-to-load-slowly-changing-dimensions-using-t-sql-merge/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the changes are all on the most current row, then you can update the current row and then insert:

```
with u as (
      update dimCustomer c
          set RowIsCurrent = 'N',
              RowEndDate = sc.ChangeDate
      from Staging_DimCustomer sc
      where sc.CustomerNum = c.CustomerNum and
            c.RowIsCurrent = 'Y'
     )
insert into dimCustomer (CustomerNum, CustomerName, Planet, RowIsCurrent, RowStartDate, RowEndDate
                         ) 
     select CustomerNum, CustomerName, Planet, 'Y', ChangeDate, '9999-12-31'::date
     from Staging_DimCustomer sc;
```

This assumes that the changes take place on the most current record.  It is rather trickier to implement historic changes, and I'm guessing that is not necessary.

Note that you might want an additional check that the row being inserted is actually different from the current row.

EDIT:

If you want to avoid changes for rows that already exist, you can do:

```
with sc as (
      select *
      from Staging_DimCustomer
      where not exists (select 1
                        from DimCustomer c
                        where c.CustomerNum = sc.CustomerNum and
                              c.CustomerName = sc.CustomerName and
                              . . .  -- whatever other columns you want to check
                      )
     ),
     u as (
      update dimCustomer c
          set RowIsCurrent = 'N',
              RowEndDate = sc.ChangeDate
      from sc
      where sc.CustomerNum = c.CustomerNum and
            c.RowIsCurrent = 'Y'
     )
insert into dimCustomer (CustomerNum, CustomerName, Planet, RowIsCurrent, RowStartDate, RowEndDate
                         ) 
     select CustomerNum, CustomerName, Planet, 'Y', ChangeDate, '9999-12-31'::date
     from sc;
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I am assuming `where not exists` go before `insert into`?

Comment: @gibbz00 . . . I realize it is a little more complicated than I specified, so I think an additional CTE is helpful to filter out the unneeded updates before making any changes.

Comment: You mentioned its trickier to implement historic changes. Is that a different scd type? I would love to learn more about that implementation type.

Comment: @gibbz00 . . . It is the same type-2 dimension, but the effective dates of the changes might not be for the most current record.  I should also add that there are additional complications if the same record is updated multiple times in the staging table.

Comment: Fascinating. I can totally envision a use case like this. Can you point toward any resource that talks about a sql scenario where the effective dates of the changes are meant for earlier records and not the current row?

Comment: @gibbz00 one example I've ran across is having a versionioning table, like if you could set a value that is accurate for the date given, the latest version can override previous values set for the same date. This creates its own history though so you do not need a type-2 dimension. In that case you end up partitioning on the day and ranking it by the version, the latest version overrides the previous values for the day. You may then also use that rank with lead/lag to create ranges that the value was good for if the value isn't set every day.

Comment: One thing to note is that when you set the row that used to be current to no longer being current you may want to set the `endDate` to the `changeDate - INTERVAL '1 DAY'` this way if you're trying to find when a record was active for there's no overlap that could yield two records. It also makes querying the table easier as you can use a `'some-date' BETWEEN startDate AND endDate` query to determine what was current during a some given date.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work fine , not updating or inserting the already existing records:

```
with us as (
  update dimCustomer c
      set RowIsCurrent = 'N',
          RowEndDate = sc.ChangeDate
  from Staging_DimCustomer sc
  where sc.CustomerNum = c.CustomerNum and
        c.RowIsCurrent = 'Y' and 
        sc.customername <> c.customername
 ),
 u as (
 select stg.customernum,stg.customername,stg.planet ,stg.changedate from Staging_DimCustomer  stg
 Inner join  DimCustomer dim on dim.customernum=stg.customernum and dim.rowiscurrent='Y'
 and (dim.customername <> stg.customername
      or dim.planet <> stg.planet
      )
 UNION
    select stg.customernum,stg.customername,stg.planet ,stg.changedate from Staging_DimCustomer  stg
 where  stg.customernum not IN(select dim.customernum  from DimCustomer dim where dim.rowiscurrent='Y')
 )
insert into dimCustomer (CustomerNum, CustomerName, Planet, RowIsCurrent, RowStartDate, RowEndDate
                     ) 
select CustomerNum, CustomerName, Planet, 'Y', ChangeDate, '9999-12-31'::date
 from  u ;
```